# Where can I ask about whether Atlantropa was actually feasible?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

[Atlantropa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantropa) was a gigantic engineering and colonisation idea from the 1920's. It involved building humongous hydroelectric dams and lowering the water level of the Mediterranean by something like 200 meters.

I want to ask whether that plan would have been possible, remotely feasible or just crazy.

Is this question suitable for any SE site at all?

What is the best site to ask it at? I have considered Earth Science and Engineering, but I'm not familiar with either site, so I'm not sure.

Comment: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)  In general, speculative questions are non-starters, unless you're on the Science Fiction and Fantasy site, or Worldbuilding, where such questions abound.

Comment: Engineering sounds like a good fit; perhaps you could check their help & ask on their Meta if it would be a good fit?

Comment: @TimMalone: From their Help Center: "Questions on Engineering Stack Exchange are usually well-received when they:

identify a specific engineering problem,
require expert engineering knowledge to solve,
Include any relevant drawings, images or references that may be necessary to understand the problem, and
excite or challenge experienced professionals in the field"

Comment: @RobertHarvey From the accepted answer of that question: `Assume that the answer is 'yes' and start designing` .... LOL!!

Comment: Anything is possible in software development if you have enough time, money and programmer talent, which makes the "is it possible" question just one extra step.  Most people asking that question are not asking how to build Skynet; their questions are far more mundane.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ...but not in engineering ;)

Comment: I don't know that site very well.  I guess you'll have to ask the Engineering folks if they're interested in engaging in that kind of speculative discourse.

Comment: @RobertHarvey http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/452/would-this-be-an-acceptable-question-here

Comment: @RobertHarvey By the way, I hope you didn't take my quote with "LOL" from the link you gave as sarcasm. (I have found that, generally, when I make jokes, sometimes it comes off as sarcasm.) I just thought of applying that advice to Alantropa, and found it funny :)

Comment: "Where can I ask about whether Atlantropa was actually feasible?" http://what-if.xkcd.com is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Braiam Great idea! I will submit it there :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question in general is a pretty bad fit for most SE sites, since it is highly speculative and open-ended. It seems to be it is pretty hard to get objective answers on this question. And a simple 'yes' or 'no' could be an valid answer, illustrating the problem even more.

A few sites were mentioned already. Let's go over them:

- Engineering: not a good fit. Since the help center asks to *identify a specific engineering problem*, which isn't the case here. See also [the reply of a moderator on Engineering meta](https://engineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/454).
- World building: not a good fit. The site header says it about *construct imaginary worlds and settings*. Your question is about an imaginary *Atlantropa*, but your question asks for real life proof, which doesn't seem to be [on-topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there.

Conclusion: there is no site that is a good fit for your question.